# "+" at end of column data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am inserting some string data into my database but find that the full word does not show up.  It will only show the first 9 characters of the word and then a "+" sign.

> Portabili+
>
> New Enrol+

instead of "Portability" and "New Enrollment".

Initially, the datatype for the column had been VARCHAR2(10 Bytes) so I thought that might be the problem.

I have since changed it to 100 bytes using an Alter Table statement and have inserted new data to see if it will show the full word but it still doesn't show.

Any ideas why?  What are all the ways/reasons why data can be auto-truncated?

> ***SOLUTION:*** I figured this out.  The answer was to change the size, however, I had to clear the cache on the application server and truncate several cache tables in the DB relating to the application.  Now the larger column size is reflected in the DB and the full word shows.

Comment: Are you using some utility or application to insert the data? or is it just a simple `INSERT` from SQL prompt (or SQL Developer or Toad)? As noted in one of the answers increasing the column size won't recover the data.

Comment: Yes, I'm using middleware BPM software to develop an application and this DB is part of the backend. I'm trying to isolate the problem from both sides.

And yes, I understand it won't recover data but that's okay.  If future inserts work properly then that'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the data was truncated on insertion. Growing the column can't bring back data that was previously truncated.

Comment: I agree that it can't bring back previously truncated data but even _after_ growing the column the data is still being truncated and there are no triggers that would alter the data before insertion.

Comment: What tool are you using to inspect the data?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Did you inserting data using DB client like SQL Developer or etc.?
Did you check inserted data using DB client (select bla bla bla)?
If so, it looks like data truncated on insertion, check `before` triggers on this table.

Comment: I have a middleware BPM program that I use to do the insert and I'm checking from that side.  I use Oracle SQL Developer to check the data and there are no triggers on that table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to size your column according to the longest value that it might hold. For a column of type "category", which it looks like you are dealing with here, a size of 128 bytes should do it.

However, values previously inserted will not be recovered when you extend alter the table definition. Future values will have no problem, though.

Comment: But if that's the case the wouldn't it throw a ORA-12899 error while insertion?

Comment: I increased the size to 128 but even after inserting new data (from the application, not SQL Developer), it is still truncating the data and adding a "+" at the end.

Comment: I don't know about specific data types in Oracle, but you should be able to set the number of characters that it can accept. Do you have the problem when you insert data from SQL Developer?